# What's the diffrence between CEF and Electron?

Tags: node.js, electron, v8, chromium-embedded

Is there anyone can tell us what is the diffrence between CEF and Electron?

And about Electron, since Electron is based on chromium, why use NodeJS instead of directly using the V8 engine in chromium

Answer (score 20):

### CEF

CEF is one of the first solutions that wrapped Chromium functionality and provided an API that can be used by third-party applications. Chromium is a standalone desktop application. CEF represents it as a framework. Since Chromium is written using C++, CEF represents a framework for C++ developers, but there are many ports for [Java](https://github.com/chromiumembedded/java-cef), [.NET](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp), and [Python](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython) languages.

The main purpose of CEF is to **let C++ developers embed Chromium into their C++ cross-desktop application** and access Chromium features like rendering (including off-screen), DOM, V8, PDF Viewer, Printing, Network requests/responses, cookies, etc.

The examples of such applications are Steam, Spotify, Adobe Brackets, and [more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_Embedded_Framework#Applications_using_CEF).

### Electron

Taking into account that CEF and Electron source codes are very similar, I can assume that:

**Electron == CEF + Node.js**

The main purpose of Electron is to **let JavaScript developers build cross-platform desktop applications** on top of Chromium. Each window in Electron app represents a Chromium window that renders specific web page or HTML. The GUI of Electron apps is built using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. The logic (backend) is written using Node.js.

### Which one to use?

CEF is for you if you are a C++ developer. It allows you both embedding Chromium into an existing C++ desktop application and creating Electron C++ cross-desktop applications.

Electron is for you if you are a JavaScript developer who wants to create a cross-desktop application with HTML, CSS, JavaScript GUI and you don't want to learn more efficient technologies and frameworks such as Qt, Gtk, Cocoa, Java Swing/JavaFX/SWT, Flutter, etc.

Answer (score 10):

Answering the second question - NodeJs supplements Chromium engine, not substitutes it in Electron. Please go through [this great article](https://blog.logrocket.com/advanced-electron-js-architecture/) to get an idea of process communication within the framework. In a nutshell - there are 2 major players over there:

- **Main** (or "host") process - running on NodeJs with access to OS functionality, responsible for windows orchestration and providing access to native functions
- **Renderer** process - actual Chromium instance with additional bindings allowing to "speak" to **Main** process

On differences between the frameworks - this is a broad question, in general they cover the same needs and most of differences are on tech side:

- Dev Tooling (Dev Language, APIs, SDKs, testing frameworks)
- Supported platforms
- Packaging and distribution options
- Performance and memory management
- Dev community adoption
- tbc

There is no clear "winner" or "loser" over there. Each of items above (and some on top) require additional research, keeping in mind your user base, dev team experience with relevant tech stack, application complexity, etc

Answer (score 10):

I'm not totally happy with either of the answers given.

Whether you're using CEF or Electron, the idea is that you're going to build the "front end"/"client" of a desktop application with browser technologies (HTML, CSS, JavaScript). This lets you write (most of) the front end once, and run on different platforms (any platform Chrome can run on). Furthermore, these frameworks allow you to use the Chromium codebase via a higher-level API, instead of having to build Chromium from source and deal with all of its complexities (to answer the second question in the OP).

[@Vladimir is right that CEF has other "embedded" use cases, such as displaying a PDF inside your application. I'm assuming in this answer that most people using either of these platforms are interested in writing cross-platform desktop applications where the "front end" is written with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. Also, there may be possibilities for embedding Electron in a similar way, either now or in the future.]

For the "back end"/"server" part of your application, you have choices with either framework. If your back end is in C++, it's true that there are some benefits to using CEF, one being that you can put the back end code in the same process/project as your CEF build, and the back end can talk to the front end directly in the process, without have to use IPC such as localhost HTTP. Similarly, if your back end is in Node, it will work with Electron without having to use IPC to talk between the client and server.

However, in both cases you can write your back end/server in whatever language/framework you want. The client/UI/application starts, launches the server process, and communicate with it. Using localhost HTTP is a nice option, because it parallels a true web-based set-up (web page talking to a remove server).

I used CEF for a long time and have recently switched to Electron. Even though my back end is in C++, I find Electron to be a better tool because you get an extra level of cross-platform functionality through Node. For example, Node has functions for showing standard open and save file dialog boxes, and taking screenshots. When using Electron, you can use Node functions for those. When using CEF, I had to write those functions separately for Macintosh and Windows. More generally, CEF is more low-level. For instance, you provide your own WNDPROC when using CEF, while with Electron you don't have to think about that level. Also, Electron is packaged as an npm module, and, compared to CEF, it's magical how you can just add Electron as a dev dependency in your package.json file, and the whole business is managed for you in a subdirectory of node_modules that you don't need to worry about.

For debugging, I can run my C++ server code in Visual Studio. Then, when my Electron application starts (by running "npm start"), it checks to see if the server is already running and if so uses it (and otherwise spawns it as a child process). The programs communicate over localhost HTTP. So it's a pretty minor difference between running the server in the same process (using C++ with CEF, or Node with Electron), versus running the server as a separate process, which lets you write the server in whatever language you want. A colleague made her server in Python and it all works the same.

In my case, it does mean there are three realms to think about: the client code (HTML, CSS, JavaScript), the Node layer (Node/JavaScript), and the C++ back end/server process. For me, the Node/JavaScript layer passes messages between the client and the C++ server, and also handles some common UI functions as described above.

Finally, Electron has many developers and a large community. From what I can tell, CEF is still developed by a very small team, so there are fewer tutorials, Stack Overflow questions, and so on. Also, using Node to provide common functions, like the dialog boxes described above, is a safer bet because there is a larger community and a more refined API than using a C++ cross-platform library like POCO.